# PDE (linear, nonhomogeneous, first order)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

Problem:

$$\frac{du}{dx} + \frac{du}{dy} + u = e^{x+2y}$$

I have tried many methods and non have given me the correct result. The best lead I had was to change the coordinates and I got:

$$\sqrt{2}\frac{du}{dx_i} + u = 0$$

(eta) = (y-x)/sqrt(2)      ,
(xi) = (x+y)/sqrt(2)

which gave me,

$$u = Ce^{-(1/\sqrt2)(eta)}$$

I don't know how to tie in the $e^{x+2y}$ to this. Any help will be extremely appreciated.

Comment: Does the substitution  $u=v e^x$ help?  I also notice that $u+w$ is also a solution if $w_1+w_2+w=0$ for example $w=Ae^{-x}+Be^{-y}$ with constant $A,B$

Answer (score 1):

Your problem seem to be what new variables to choose. Let me give an argument and solve a bit on the way, and then leave it to you to finish.

This problem calls for a linear change of variables. We fix one of the new variables ($\eta$) to fit with the exponential function in the right-hand side, and leave the other ($\xi$) open to be able to fit it to the differential equation below. Thus, let
$$
\xi=x+ay,\quad\text{and}\quad \eta=x+2y,
$$
where $a$ is to be chosen below. Also, we write $v(\xi,\eta)=u(x,y)$. Then, by the chain rule,
$$
u'_x=v'_\xi+v'_\eta,\quad\text{and}\quad u'_y=av'_\xi+2v'_\eta.
$$
Now, $a$ should be chosen so that the differential equation becomes as simple as possible. The left-hand side is transformed into
$$
u'_x+u'_y+u=(a+1)v'_\xi+3v'_\eta+v,
$$
while the right-hand side is transformed into $e^\eta$.

Now, with $a=-1$, the new differential equation becomes
$$
3v'_\eta+v=e^\eta.
$$
Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{du}{dx} + \frac{du}{dy} + u = e^{x+2y}$$

Let : $\quad u(x,y)=v(x,y)+\frac{1}{4}e^{x+2y}$

$$\frac{dv}{dx} + \frac{dv}{dy} = -v$$

System of characteristic differential equations :

$$\frac{dx}{1}=\frac{dy}{1}=\frac{dv}{-v}$$

First characteristic equation from $\frac{dx}{1}=\frac{dy}{1}\qquad\to\qquad x-y=c_1$

Second characteristic equation from $\frac{dx}{1}=\frac{dv}{-v}\qquad\to\qquad v\:e^x=c_2$

General solution on implicit form, with any differentiable function $\Phi(X,Y)$ :
$$\Phi\left(x-y\:,\:v\:e^x  \right)=0$$

Solving for $Y\qquad\to\qquad Y=v\:e^x=F(X)=F(x-y)$ :
$$v=e^{-x}F(x-y)$$
where $F$ is any differentiable function.
$$u(x,y)=e^{-x}F(x-y)+\frac{1}{4}e^{x+2y}$$
Note:

This is equivalent to  $$u(x,y)=e^{-x}e^{x-y}G(x-y)+\frac{1}{4}e^{x+2y}=e^{-y}G(x-y)+\frac{1}{4}e^{x+2y}$$
 with any differentiable function $G$